# How to get first commit message when multiple commits are pushed together

Tags: bash, github, git-commit, git-log, github-enterprise

I am trying to write a pre-receive hook script to link git commits with jira id. I want to verify if the first commit, which will become heading of my pull request follows the specified regex for commit message. 
Can you please help me to get the commit message of 1st commit in series of commits in a pull request

I am following below steps in my branch:

```
git add file1
git commit -m 'JIRA-123 Adding file1'
git add file2
git commit -m 'Adding file2'
git push origin master
```

Now I am able to get last commit message specific to a push using below command

```
git log --max-count=1 --format=%B
```

> Output:  Adding file2

but I want the output to be first commit message-

> JIRA-123 Adding file1

Can you please let me know if there's a way to get the desired result using `git log` or `git reflog`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

## Generic way

In general, git doesn't know how many commits you are going to include in your PR. Therefore, it's hard to select appropriate commit message for your PR. So, you can point specific commit using it's [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

Let's say `git commit -m 'JIRA-123 Adding file1'` returned something like that:

```sh
$ git commit -m 'JIRA-123 Adding file1'
> [master de56f51] JIRA-123 Adding file1
> 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

`de56f51` - is SHA1 of that commit

So,you can get comment of that commit using `git show`:

```sh
$ git show de56f51 --pretty=%B --no-patch
> JIRA-123 Adding file1
```

## More specific ways

### If you have *exactly* two commits per PR

If you certainly sure that count of your commits equals 2, then you can use previous answer:

```sh
git log --max-count=1 --format=%B HEAD~1
```

### If you have no more then one PR *per day*

If you have no more then one PR *per day*, then you may use

```sh
git log --since=yesterday --max-count=1 --format=%B
```

It will show comment for the first today commit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *revision range* like

```
git log HEAD~1
```

> A suffix ~ to a revision parameter means the commit object that
>              is the th generation ancestor of the named commit object,
>              following only the first parents.